# Setting output variable in deep learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have this code:

```
from numpy import loadtxt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
dataset = loadtxt('pima-indians-diabetes.csv', delimiter=',')
X = dataset[:,0:8]
y = dataset[:,8]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, epochs=150, batch_size=10)
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(X, y)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))
```

I need to change the output column so it predicts/learns from a score(for instance 1 to a million) instead of 0 or 1(sigmoid).

Comment: Seems you are trying to do regression rather than classification. Use `model.add(Dense(1))`, no activation so it will be linear layer. Also change the loss to `mse` from `binary_crossentropy`

Comment: @epsi95 thanks for that, bonus question, do you know how to make it take a varying amount of columns as input data? say 4 to 5? right now my columns are all size 8 and I'm having to pad it but worry that it will mess with the learning.

Comment: Please do not use the comments space for follow-up questions. Either edit & update your post or open a new one.

Answer (score 0):

As for your case you need to use relu as your activation function in the last layer (output layer) instead of sigmoid
The range of relu is [0,inf).Then in that case you need to use 'MSE' as your loss metric.

Conceptually, the problem which you are trying to solve is a regression type of problem.